# How to pass all tests in HashTable HakerRank assignment?

Tags: java, hashtable

I don't understand why only 8/17 test cases are passed using my solution of [Hash Tables: Ransom Note HakerRank challenge](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-ransom-note).

Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int m = in.nextInt();
        int n = in.nextInt();
        HashMap<String, Integer> magazine = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for(int magazine_i=0; magazine_i < m; magazine_i++){
            String word = in.next();
            Integer wordCounter = magazine.get(word);
            if(wordCounter != null){
                magazine.put(word, ++wordCounter);
            }else{
                magazine.put(word, 1);
            }
        }
        HashMap<String, Integer> ransom = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        for(int ransom_i=0; ransom_i < n; ransom_i++){
            String word = in.next();
            Integer wordCounter = ransom.get(word);
            if(wordCounter != null){
                ransom.put(word, ++wordCounter);
            }else{
                ransom.put(word, 1);
            }
        }
        boolean ok = true;
        breakpoint:
        for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> ransomEntry: ransom.entrySet()){
            if(magazine.get(ransomEntry.getKey()) != null){
                if(magazine.get(ransomEntry.getKey()) < ransomEntry.getValue()){
                   ok = false;
                   break breakpoint;
                }
            }else{
               ok = false;
               break breakpoint;
            }

        }
        if(ok){
            System.out.println("Yes");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Well, for a start, your code always ends up printing Yes.

Comment: Now it never prints No. Why don't you just test your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem (from what I can see) with the original code, not necessarily the edited version, is the double output on negative results. If the ransomer cannot make the note, your code prints both "No," and "Yes." All you needed to do was add curly brackets opening after the `breakpoint` label, and close them **after** the "Yes" print line. Learn to test your code.